# How to rename subpackage folder name in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using WaveMaker and Eclipse IDE. In WaveMaker,I create java services and  edit them using eclipse. Have to set its default service package's path into `services/serviceName/src` package folder.Right clicking on src folder and select 'Use as Source Folder' option open another window.

Now the problem is:

my folder name is now : `services/serviceName/src/com/subpackage1/subpackage2/subpackage3/subpackage4/subpackage5`

I want to rename it as `services/serviceName/src` with default package in which java file is there. Its not allowing me to rename it as above..

Below is the screenshot.[image]

I want to rename it to services/userSignupService/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I was giving full path name while creating java service in wavemaker. I've created it without full path. and in Eclipse, Right Click>Build Path>Use as source folder works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're slightly mistaken here.

`services/serviceName/src/com/subpackage1/subpackage2` is not the name of your folder. It is just the full package path.

Your `services/serviceName/src` will still be there if you can go to the workspace in Windows Explorer and *explore*

Comment: @bsm you can also open up the `Navigator` view in Eclipse and have a look

Comment: Yes I have checked it but want to know right click>Build path>Use as source folder which opens one window but not getting when I make changes in folder name and it doesnt allow me for it.

Comment: But my question is still there.Whether can I rename it or not?and How? May be got confused..

Comment: @bsm Yes, I think you confused me too :) Can you post a screenshot of what you're talking about?